# Failed to make query with an explicit join sequence (including alias table) on SQLAlchemy

Tags: join, sqlalchemy, alias, explicit

I have trouble on making a SQLAlchemy query between two tables:

```
ProcessedDataset
    - ID 
ProcDSParent
    - ThisDataset (foreign key to ProcessedDataset.ID)
    - ItsParent   (foreign key to ProcessedDataset.ID)
```

To find the `Parent` and `Child` of a `Dataset`, I need explicit
specify the join sequence between:
`ProcessedDataset` <-- `ProcDSParent` --> `ProcessedDataset`

After make different alias for them, I try different join approach,
but still not able to get it.

Demonstrate with find `Parent` of a `Dataset`:

```
dataset = DB.db_tables[db_alias]['ProcessedDataset']
dsparent = DB.db_tables[db_alias]['ProcDSParent']

parent = dataset.alias('ProcessedDataset_ItsParent')
child_parent = dsparent.alias('ThisDataset_ItsParent')

keylist = [parent.c.Name]
whereclause = dataset.c.Name.op('=')('Test')
```

---

- Approach <1>:

### FromClause.join + expression.select

```
r_join = dataset
r_join.join(child_parent, dataset.c.ID == child_parent.c.ThisDataset)
r_join.join(parent, child_parent.c.ItsParent == parent.c.ID)

query = select(keylist, from_obj=r_join, whereclause=whereclause)

print query
SELECT `ProcessedDataset_ItsParent`.`Name`
FROM `ProcessedDataset` AS `ProcessedDataset_ItsParent`, `ProcessedDataset`
WHERE `ProcessedDataset`.`Name` = %s
```

---

- Approach <2>:

### orm.join + expression.select

```
join2 = join(dataset, child_parent, dataset.c.ID == child_parent.c.ThisDataset)
join2.join(dsparent, child_parent.c.ItsParent == parent.c.ID)

print query
SELECT `ProcessedDataset_ItsParent`.`Name`
FROM `ProcessedDataset` AS `ProcessedDataset_ItsParent`,
     `ProcessedDataset` INNER JOIN `ProcDSParent` AS `ThisDataset_ItsParent` ON
     `ProcessedDataset`.`ID` = `ThisDataset_ItsParent`.`ThisDataset`
WHERE `ProcessedDataset`.`Name` = %s
```

---

As you can see, none of them are `Parent` of a `Dataset`, which should be:

```
SELECT `ProcessedDataset_ItsParent`.`Name`
FROM `ProcessedDataset` 
   INNER JOIN `ProcDSParent` AS `ThisDataset_ItsParent` ON  
          `ProcessedDataset`.`ID` = `ThisDataset_ItsParent`.`ThisDataset`
   INNER JOIN `ProcessedDataset` AS `ProcessedDataset_ItsParent` ON
          `ThisDataset_ItsParent`.'ItsParent` = `ProcessedDataset_ItsParent`.`ID`
WHERE `ProcessedDataset`.`Name` = %s
```

Appreciate for any help, stuck here for couple of days already!

Dong

## Attaching minimal DDL and python code

```
CREATE TABLE ProcessedDataset
  (
    ID                    BIGINT UNSIGNED not null auto_increment,
    Name                  varchar(500)      not null,

    primary key(ID)
  ) ;


CREATE TABLE ProcDSParent
  (
    ID                    BIGINT UNSIGNED not null auto_increment,
    ThisDataset           BIGINT UNSIGNED   not null,
    ItsParent             BIGINT UNSIGNED   not null,

    primary key(ID),
    unique(ThisDataset,ItsParent)
  ) ;

ALTER TABLE ProcDSParent ADD CONSTRAINT 
    ProcDSParent_ThisDataset_FK foreign key(ThisDataset) references ProcessedDataset(ID) on delete CASCADE
;
ALTER TABLE ProcDSParent ADD CONSTRAINT 
    ProcDSParent_ItsParent_FK foreign key(ItsParent) references ProcessedDataset(ID) on delete CASCADE
;

INSERT INTO ProcessedDataset VALUES (0, "ds0");
INSERT INTO ProcessedDataset VALUES (1, "ds1");
INSERT INTO ProcessedDataset VALUES (2, "ds2");
INSERT INTO ProcessedDataset VALUES (3, "ds3");
INSERT INTO ProcessedDataset VALUES (4, "ds4");
INSERT INTO ProcessedDataset VALUES (5, "ds5");
INSERT INTO ProcessedDataset VALUES (6, "ds6");
INSERT INTO ProcessedDataset VALUES (7, "ds7");

INSERT INTO ProcDSParent VALUES (0, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO ProcDSParent VALUES (1, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO ProcDSParent VALUES (2, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO ProcDSParent VALUES (3, 3, 4);
INSERT INTO ProcDSParent VALUES (4, 5, 6);
INSERT INTO ProcDSParent VALUES (5, 7, 6);
```

(ds0, ds2)-> ds1 -> ds3 -> ds4

(ds5, ds7) -> ds6

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy import and_
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import join


url = 'mysql://cms:passcms@localhost:3306/testbed'
engine = create_engine(url, strategy = 'threadlocal')
kwargs = {'autoload':True}
db_meta = MetaData()
db_meta.bind = engine

dataset = Table('ProcessedDataset', db_meta, **kwargs)
dsparent = Table('ProcDSParent', db_meta, **kwargs)

parent = dataset.alias('ProcessedDataset_ItsParent')
child_parent = dsparent.alias('ThisDataset_ItsParent')

keylist = [parent.c.Name]
whereclause = dataset.c.Name.op('=')('ds0')

r_join = dataset
r_join.join(child_parent, dataset.c.ID == child_parent.c.ThisDataset)
r_join.join(parent, child_parent.c.ItsParent == parent.c.ID)

query = select(keylist, whereclause)
print query
print engine.execute(query).fetchall()

query.append_from(r_join)
print query
print engine.execute(query).fetchall()

query = select(keylist, from_obj=r_join, whereclause=whereclause)
print query
print engine.execute(query).fetchall()

join2 = join(dataset, child_parent, dataset.c.ID == child_parent.c.ThisDataset)
join2.join(dsparent, child_parent.c.ItsParent == parent.c.ID)


query.append_from(join2)
print query
print engine.execute(query).fetchall()

query = select(keylist, from_obj=join2, whereclause=whereclause)
print query
print engine.execute(query).fetchall()
```

Comment: Could you create a standalone testcase?

Comment: @plaes attached the minimal DDL and Python code, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Michael Bayer Replied my via mail.

the `join()` method returns a new Join object, that's the one which represents the join.  The original object is unchanged:

```
r_join = dataset
r_join = r_join.join(child_parent, ...)
r_join = r_join.join(parent, ...)
```

AND also I tried out the `orm.join`:

```
join1 = join(child_parent, dataset, child_parent.c.ThisDataset == dataset.c.ID)
join2 = parent.join(join1, parent.c.ID == child_parent.c.ItsParent)
```